# How to show HTML with Tag in Datatables using JSON Date?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

i am using datatables for listing details and i getting datas from another page. 
JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#app_table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        'serverMethod': 'post',
        'ajax': {
            'url': "ajax/list_app.php"
        },
        'columns': [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'Name' },
            { data: 'Referral_ID' },
            {
                data: null,render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    // Combine the first and last names into a single table field
                    return data.action;
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

And My Json Data is

```
{"draw":1,"iTotalRecords":"1","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[{"id":1,"Name":"Test","Referral_ID":"5ED91AF864754","action":"<select class='edit_status form-control' name='edit_status' style='width: 88px;'>\r\n            <option value=''>Select<\/option>\r\n            <option data-id='' value='Yes'  >Yes<\/option>\r\n            <option data-id='' value='No'  >No<\/option>\r\n        <\/select>"}]}
```

But displays like htmlentities(). Any one have a solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The data in the question is not valid JSON. You can check it [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Sorry bro updated json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did not find what i am expect but i had a solution. We can handle using direct HTML Link JSX

```
{
                data: null,render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    // Combine the first and last names into a single table field
                    return "<select class='edit_status form-control' name='edit_status' style='width: 88px;'>\n" +
                        "            <option value=''>Select</option>\n" +
                        "            <option data-id='"+data.san_id+"' value='Yes' >Yes</option>\n" +
                        "            <option data-id='"+data.san_id+"' value='No' >No</option>\n" +
                        "        </select>";

                }
            },
```

Comment: Just out of interest: Using `{ data: 'action' }` instead of the above works for me. It displays the same drop-down as the above approach. Does that approach work in your code, also? It just displays the related string - which happens to be the HTML for a drop-down.